# problem enabling wireless and wired networking at the same time

Tags: networking

I have a computer with one wireless (wlan0) and 2 wired (eth0 and eth1) network ports.
I want this scenario:

1. wlan0 and eth0 to use dhcp for connection to the internet on boot, with wired taking priority.
2. eth1 to be always on with static IP so that I can plug my laptop in and connect directly with ssh if needed.

I've tried to configure this with NetworkManager but when I enable eth1 it always disables the wireless.  I've checked the box "use this connection only for resources on this network" for all interfaces....

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple interfaces on a computer in the same subnet. This can cause routing issues and loops. And if you have an intelligent switch which recognizes it, it will shut down one of your interfaces.
So you need to keep all your interfaces on separate subnets.

Comment: I'm trying to set wlan0 and eth0 to different subnets. wlan0 will get its public IP via dhcp and eth0 will be manually set to 192.168.1.7  Still ubuntu will not allow this