# Wifi is disconnecting when a wired ethernet connection is made

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

I am fairly new to Ubuntu.

My issue is on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I boot up I can connect to wifi, which is established through the use of a USB network antenna. I am working with a slave device that I want to communicate with over ethernet, and whenever I plug it into an open ethernet port it disconnects my wifi. I was able to solve this issue by assigning it a static IP address; however there are times where I need to set the method to Automatic (DHCP) and when I do this is when I encounter the error again.

Just to be clear: I can go into Network and set the wired connection (eth1) to OFF and the wifi will turn on; however, when I turn eth1 to ON the wifi immediately disconnects.

I did find this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430543/problem-enabling-wireless-and-wired-networking-at-the-same-time) and I understand it, but I don't know exactly how to go about assigning a new subnet. Is this the right route to take? How do I do this?

I think I understand that what is happening is the ethernet port is taking priority, but how do I tell the network manager that I want both to be connected at the same time using DHCP?

If there is any other information that I can provide please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI:  the 16.04 means the 2016-April release, which came with 5 years of *standard* support, ie. reaching EOL for *standard* support  in 2021-April; with *extended* support available (ESM) at cost or via coupon from Canonical. ESM releases are off-topic here.  I suggest you change your question to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu, as then we can help you, or explore the ESM support options for your release.